# RxBinding Documentation

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rx-binding

RxBinding does not have its own documentation. The commands may be easy for professional developers but not for beginners. Does anyone have a self-documented documentation or a link that has ample resources ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this links:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jakewharton.rxbinding.widget.RxTextView

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jakewharton.rxbinding.view.RxView

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/rxjava-for-android-apps-introducing-rxbinding-and-rxlifecycle--cms-28565

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/RxJava-and-RxBinding

https://medium.freecodecamp.com/simplifying-recyclerview-adapters-with-rx-databinding-f02ebed0b386

https://medium.com/crunching-rxandroid/crunching-rxandroid-part-6-6149764b59e

https://academy.realm.io/posts/donn-felker-reactive-android-ui-programming-with-rxbinding/

Also, search in Medium, there is a lot of people writing about it.

Comment: Your welcome, If you think if the answer helps you, please mark as correct answer.